# Close connections related to SimpleMessageListenerContainer in Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am currently working on an event-based async AMQP message listener, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleAmqpConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "container")
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        container.setQueueName("some.queue");
        container.setMessageListener(exampleListener());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener exampleListener() {
        return new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                System.out.println("received: " + message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have changed the container bean's autostart property to false. And I have autowired this bean to an event lister that starts the container when StartEvent happens:

```
@EventListener
public void startContainer(StartEvent startEvent) {
     this.container.start();
}
```

At the same time, I have also autowired the bean to another event that stops the container and shutdowns the container, hoping that the container will be stopped and that there will be no lingering connection:

```
@EventListener
public void endContainer(EndEvent endEvent) {
     this.container.stop();
     this.container.shutdown();
}
```

However, after the EndEvent, I find in my RabbitMQ admin console that all the channels are closed but there is still a lingering connection.

Does that mean that shutdown() is not the right method to use to remove the lingering connection?  If that's the case, what is the right method to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `resetConnection()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory` to close the connection; as implied by the class name; the connection is cached.